# Laravel - Delete data record from Database

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I want to delete record Photo and Photo_list from Database but give me error

[image: This is my database Product]

This is my Code in Controller

```
public function deletephoto($id)
{

    $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
    Product::select('photo','photo_list')->delete($product->id);

    return redirect(route('stores.index'));

}
```

Comment: And what error do you get ?

Comment: Do you want to delete two columns value or full row?

Comment: I think he just wants to clear two columns and not as the answers show

Comment: two columns...photo and photo list

Comment: i think you are talking about changing columns value ... not deleted entire column ... you can see my answer .... hope it will help you

Comment: give me error like this "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StoreController::deletephoto()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
public function deletephoto($id)
    {

        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
        if($product){
          $product->photo= null;
          $product->photo_list= null;
          $product->save();
        }

        return redirect(route('stores.index'));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Before @Minar Mnr...but give me error like this "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StoreController::deletephoto()"

Comment: When you call deletephoto() function ... did you pass parameter ...like this deletephoto($id);

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can delete specific data with delete.
Delete is used to remove a row.

You will need to update your table with a request like that :

```
public function deletephoto($id)
{

    $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
    Product::where('id', 100)->update(['photo' => NULL, 'photo_list' => NULL]);

    return redirect(route('stores.index'));

}
```

You can see more here : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#updates 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 0):

```
public function deletephoto($id)
{

    $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
    Product::Where('id','=',$product->id)->delete();

    return redirect(route('stores.index'));

}
```

Or you can directly do this

```
Product::find($id)->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks Before @Adnan Mumtaz...but give me error like this "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StoreController::deletephoto()"

Comment: @FaizFurios52 dear make sure you are passing id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Product::WhereProductId($product->id)->delete();
```